# Appending to list replaces all items in the list with most recent item

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

So this is what I have. What I get at the end I have a list of every element in the formattedList the same. But when I print features[i] it prints the right features that I want to add to the end of the list.

```
# function to change modified json list back to dict so it can be saved as a json file again
def makeDict(jsonlist):
    features = [{}] * 364
    geoid1 = [{}] * 364
    geometry = [{}] * 364
    properties = [{}] * 364
    formattedList = []
    tempList = []
    keylistfeatures = ['geometry', 'properties']
    keylistgeometry = ['coordinates', 'type']
    keylistproperties = ['content', 'datatype', 'density', 'density', 'description', 'display', 'file', 'size', 'source'
                         , 'target']
    keylistfile = ['date', 'name', 'size']
    file = {}
    size = []
    density = []

    for i in range(0, 364):
        # make density list
        density = [jsonlist[i][6], jsonlist[i][7]]
        # size list
        size = [jsonlist[i][8], jsonlist[i][9]]
        # file dictionary
        file['date'] = jsonlist[i][1]
        file['name'] = jsonlist[i][0]
        file['size'] = jsonlist[i][2]
        # geometry dictionary
        geometry[i]['coordinates'] = jsonlist[i][11]
        geometry[i]['type'] = jsonlist[i][12]
        # properties dictionary
        properties[i]['content'] = jsonlist[i][5]
        properties[i]['datatype'] = jsonlist[i][4]
        properties[i]['density'] = density
        properties[i]['description'] = jsonlist[i][10]
        properties[i]['display'] = jsonlist[i][3]
        properties[i]['file'] = file
        properties[i]['size'] = size
        properties[i]['source'] = jsonlist[i][14]
        properties[i]['target'] = jsonlist[i][15]
        features[i]['geometry'] = geometry[i]
        features[i]['properties'] = properties[i]
        features[i]['type'] = jsonlist[i][13]
        # print(features[i])
        formattedList.append(features[i])
    # print(formattedList)
    return formattedList
```

Been stuck on this for hours but my guess is it's something simple I don't understand.
When I use the debugger, here is what I see

[1st iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsJwc.png)

[2nd iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bt8G7.png)

[3rd iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTnw8.png)

[4th iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ky0D.png)

And also features is always a list of 364 of the same thing for that iteration
[features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNZyE.png)

Comment: `features = [{}] * 364` creates exactly one list, and  *one* dictionary - the list contains 364 references to that one dict.  You want something like `features = [{} for _ in range(364)]` that actually creates individual dicts.  (Similar problems exist throughout your code.)

Comment: @jasonharper Okay, I was following the example at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-initialize-list-with-empty-dictionaries/

Using this method does not affect the issue. Though i understand this way is better so we're not using a single reference.

Comment: Nevertheless, that's the problem here. That url has specifically says "The drawback is that similar reference dictionaries will be made which will point to similar memory location." Which is exactly what is happening. And then they propose the exact same solution as "method 2"

Comment: @KennyOstrom Sorry for my miscommunication, I meant using the method in the second half of that link and as suggested by jasonharper. I still had the same problem for some of them and it didn't match what features[i] prints out. However since making that comment I realized there was more initializers that needed to be changed and I have solved the problem with jasonharper's method.

Thank you both immensely for helping me find it. Next time I'll read my source more carefully, this would have been avoided if I kept scrolling after I thought I found what I was looking for.